# How do i make the text that is added to the textBox to be added only once and not all the time since is in a loop?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker; 
    List<string> tempNamesAndTexts = new List<string>();
    string tempDownload = downloadContent();
    GetProfileNames(tempDownload);
    GetTextFromProfile(tempDownload);
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
    {
        tempNamesAndTexts.Add(names[i] + " " + texts[i]);            
    }
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tempNamesAndTexts.ForEach(Item => textBox1.AppendText(Item + Environment.NewLine))));
    }
    while (true)
    {
        namesAndTexts = new List<string>();
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string content = downloadContent();
            GetProfileNames(content);
            GetTextFromProfile(content);
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
            {
                 namesAndTexts.Add(names[i] + " " + texts[i]);
            }
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                bool result = tempNamesAndTexts.SequenceEqual(namesAndTexts);
                if (result == true)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    var t = namesAndTexts.Last();

                    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(t + Environment.NewLine)), null);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(t + Environment.NewLine)), null);
                                    return;
```

If i will put a reutn; or break; it will keep adding the variable t nonstop to the textBox. And i want it to be added only once. And the loop will continue but that the variable t will be added only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understand well your question, it sounds that you simply need to check on

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) //ADD NEW TEXT ONLY IF THERE IS NO ANY
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(t + Environment.NewLine)), null);
```

This *without* `return` naturally, so the `while` loop will continue to run.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: Tigran no i dont want to check if the textBox1.Text is null or empty. I want to add the string variable t only once when the IF condition is false. There is bool there if you see and if its true it does nothing if its false it will enter and will add the variable T to the textBox1 . The problem is that this t variable is in the while(true) loop and once it was added to the textBox for some reason it will stuck there and the loop will keep adding the variable t to the textBox so instead in the textBox to see for example the stringt:"Hi All" once i will see it adding nonstop.

Comment: I need somehow to add the t to the textBox when the bool if false but once only ! and also to keep the loop going on. In this case as it is now its stuck in this t variable line and keep adding the t variable nonstop times ot textBox.

Comment: Fixed it . Will publish my solution in the question soon. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to be updated each time through the loop, then you could always remove the first line of the current string, and then append what remains to the (t + Environment.NewLine). That's a lot of string cutting though. If you want a counter, you might as well just add a progress bar.

If that's not what you're looking for, then I've misunderstood your question. Please clarify.